# Query MySQL where an XML is the value

Tags: python, mysql, xml, buffer

I am working on a search tool that queries MySQL, finds UniqueID and links it to several other tables. Generating variables and Text in my window with a thumbnail. That's all the easy part. I've run into an area where the Selected entry in SQL is an XML file only as a value instead of a file.

Interactively, I can work with this XML no problem when I save it as a file. And read it back into elementTree parser. But once I try and xml parse the list I get from the cursor.fetchall() method I get errors about can only parse from a file or buffered string not a list. I'm new to XML and MySQL (in python), any help would be greatly appreciated!

In short, I'm trying to parse a list as an XML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the error message (unluckily you did not include the error traceback) indicates that you receive a list of values. This is the expected result when running fetchall(). It will return a list of rows returned and the rows will be list-like objects with the fields. This applies even if there is only one row or only one value returned.

You will have to

- use fetchone()
- use an index: `result[0]`
- iterate over the result: `for row in result:`

And use an index on the row to get the field.

```
for row in result:
    parser_function(row[0])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, The fetchone()and fetchall() methods produce the same result. Which is a list and the first  item is the entire XML. Ian able to convert list to string, then split("\\n")  the string into a real list. I can get the values via regex from here, but Am still searching for a way to parse into XML, it's quite a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
c.execute("SQLQUERY")
result = c.fetchone()
tree = ET.fromstring(result[0])
tree
<Element 'cut' at 0x10f3cd5500>
```

Using result didn't work, must be result[0]. I overlooked it because the whole tuple was 1 element containing an XML string.